# How to access iPhone Photo Albums like PHOTOGENE

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I know this question is asked hundred times. but there is no answer to how to fetch all the images in appstore friendly way without UserInteraction.

I would like to know how `PHOTOGENE` is getting the albums and displaying them in a grid. How the app can change the thumb nail sizes and pick one image. it shows different albums and one image for each album. mind boggling!!
what I am looking for is a smart way to access the iPhone album using UIImagePickerController without user interaction.

**How is [PHOTOGENE](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photogene-for-ipad/id363448251?mt=8) accessing iPhone albums?!**

amazing what they have done!

Comment: AssetsLibrary solved this problem. you can find example here [https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can check in the ALAssetsLibrary (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as the documentation says, it gives you access to:

> The videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

Comment: i wanna kiss you man! that is exactly what i was looking for.

was able to get list of albums and its thumbnails. number of photos in each albums and each photos in all the albums. thumbnails and full photos.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. This tutorial goes through this.

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821.

It will not work in simulator only in device. Just for your information.

Hope it helps.